# How do I enable Goblin sieges in a fortress that's not near a Goblin civ?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I only have Elves and Humans to kill in my map and would like Goblins and/or Kobolds to show up as well.  My embark site doesn't have those features, but I'm on a really awesome map otherwise and would just like to go and hack some files to get more sieging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, if civilizations are dead, you can't interact with them.

This being said, if you use DFHack, Putnam made a script that "forces" a certain event to happen. The script can be downloaded from [DFFD](http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=7367). Just place the compressed file in DFHack's `hack/scripts` folder.

To create a goblin siege, write in DFHack's terminal:

> force siege EVIL

(EVIL being the goblin's ID ingame). The script is finicky and the siege may not appear immediately, but if I remember correctly, it should create the event. The script can also force other events, but as I said earlier, it is finicky.